# Как при помощи лямбда выражения описать try catch?

Tags: java

Например:

```
public double getMax() {
    try {
        if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
            double max = list.get(0).x + list.get(0).y;
            for (Object obj : list) {
                if (obj.x + obj.y > max)
                    max = obj.x + obj.y;
            }
            return max;
        } else {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: а где тут лямбда-выражение?

Comment: при помощи лямбда выражения описать try catch

Comment: @hellog888 никак

Comment: [orElseThrow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double max;
if (list == null) {
    max = 0.0
} else {
    max = list.stream()
        .mapToDouble(it -> it.x + it.y)
        .max()
        .orElse(0.0);
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]